# Can anyone provide maven dependency for xmlparserv2.jar

Tags: maven, parsing

I am trying to add dependency for xmlparserv2.jar but could find anywhere.
Any help please.

Thanks

Comment: I made a mistake on artifactId section of dependency, it was artifactId.jar but it should be just artifactId. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has a maven repository and to be able to use it you have to create an account and make some configuration for maven. xmlparserv2.jar(and some other jars) is served in that repository. There is a detailed post about this at [oracle blogs](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides)

After that you can add dependency like this.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Or

After creating account you can directly download the jar from the following location
https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1/xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar

This site will ask username(email you provided during the account creation) and password to proceed to download.

There is also a jar that is uploaded to mulesoft [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/xmlparserv2/9i) by someone(it looks like a fairly old version.)  (Using this might be a violation to Oracle license agreement)

Comment: Hi , I tried everything, but still unable to access this jar. Is there any other site where i could find this jar?

Comment: @Neethu See edit, I am able to download the jar from https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content/com/oracle/jdbc/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1/xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar this link. You have to register and validate your email to download it.

Comment: @Neethu After downloading the jar you can install it to your local repo if you wish to. Explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: Could you send me the dependency for this. When i click on this link it is getting downloaded directly. In my case, i want to put this as a dependency in pom, so that it will be picked by during build

Comment: @Neethu To use it as dependency you must follow the steps given in the oracle blog. But after downloading you can install this to your local maven repo or upload to your remote repository if you have one.